# Import data from one Azure Application Insight to another Application Insight

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I know, it's possible to export data from an App Insight account. Is it possible to import data (telemetry) into App insights account from another App insights account?

Comment: Just for query or store in another app insights?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, but you can do queries across application insights, so this is probably not needed

Comment: @IvanYang, store in another app insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to import from one to another.  you *could* by exporting it, swapping out the ikey and sending it again, but it's probably not worth that extra work. but even doing that has limitations on how "old" the data can be (you can't export 30 days and import and get 30 days in the new resource.  any data more than ~48h old (last time I checked) will be rejected.

you can do queries across multiple application insights resources, either via the logs tool or workbooks, so it's probably easier to just query both resources instead?

Comment: i like the idea of querying from both resources! That solves our problem

Comment: Hey is this is still true as of October 2022?

Comment: i don't believe there's a way to move like that, however, now application insights supports Log Analytics Workspace based AI, where the events from MANY app insights resources end up in the same logs workspace.  you can then query across resources by querying in the workspace, and query single resources by querying them as AI resources